# pandas dataframe delete duplicates on 2 columns if the third is different

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to solve the following problem using pandas. I would like to delete rows that have the same id and y value and have a different z column. Here is a simple example:

```
  id  y  z
0  a  0  3
1  a  0  1
2  a  0  3
3  b  3  4
4  b  0  2
5  b  0  2
```

I would like to obtain the following result

```
  id  y  z
0  b  3  4
1  b  0  2
2  b  0  2
```

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: What code have you written for this? Please share it so that the community can review it and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
x = df.set_index(['id', 'y'])
x.loc[x.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(lambda k: k.duplicated(keep=False).all() or k.size==1).z].reset_index()

    id  y   z
0   b   3   4
1   b   0   2
2   b   0   2
```

Comment: Sorry I just got back from vacation. It's working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @FrDad76 glad I could help ;) Please consider accepting the aswer for future referrals ;)